# launchd jobs exit status -44

Tags: macos, launchd, signal

Anyone knows what does the -44 exit statues mean or can lead me to find relevant informations?

```
PID     Status  Label
-       0       com.apple.SafariHistoryServiceAgent
-       0       com.google.keystone.user.xpcservice
64048   0       com.apple.quicklook
-       0       com.apple.parentalcontrols.check
337     0       com.apple.Finder
-       0       com.apple.PackageKit.InstallStatus
489     0       com.apple.mediaremoteagent
-       0       com.apple.FontWorker
346     0       com.apple.bird
-       0       com.apple.familycontrols.useragent
-       0       com.apple.universalaccessAuthWarn
434     0       com.apple.nsurlsessiond
420     0       com.google.android.mtpagent.3512
-       0       com.apple.syncservices.uihandler
62494   -44     com.apple.SafariBookmarksSyncAgent
62321   -44     com.apple.iconservices.iconservicesagent
62420   -44     com.apple.ContactsAgent
-       0       com.apple.ManagedClientAgent.agent
-       0       com.apple.screensharing.agent
-       0       com.apple.TMHelperAgent.SetupOffer
-       0       com.apple.AddressBook.SourceSync
-       0       com.apple.languageassetd
-       0       com.apple.familynotificationd
62320   -44     com.apple.photolibraryd
-       0       com.apple.cfnetwork.cfnetworkagent
-       0       com.apple.xpc.otherbsd
-       0       com.apple.sysdiagnose_agent
2029    0       com.apple.Preview.3072
-       0       com.apple.universalaccessHUD
-       0       com.apple.bluetoothUIServer
-       0       com.skype.skype.shareagent
-       0       com.apple.assistant_service
-       0       com.apple.touristd
-       0       com.apple.MRTa
62092   -44     com.apple.CommCenter
59546   -44     com.apple.trustd.agent
-       0       com.apple.MailServiceAgent
-       -44     com.apple.appkit.xpc.sandboxedServiceRunner
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.mail
-       -44     com.apple.mdworker.single.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
64040   0       com.apple.mdworker.shared.04000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3425AMD_i386_1
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3425AMD_i386
326     0       com.apple.cfprefsd.xpc.agent
-       0       com.apple.unmountassistant.useragent
-       0       com.apple.java.InstallOnDemand
-       0       com.apple.DataDetectorsLocalSources
444     0       com.apple.keyboardservicesd
-       78      net.sf.ulogin.cleanup
64063   -44     com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent
-       0       com.apple.csuseragent
-       0       com.apple.CoreRAIDAgent
-       0       com.apple.AOSPushRelay
387     0       com.apple.SocialPushAgent
-       0       com.apple.DeviceSupportUpdater
-       0       com.apple.apsctl
-       0       com.apple.xpc.loginitemregisterd
-       0       com.apple.coreservices.UASharedPasteboardProgressUI
530     0       com.apple.applespell
62203   -44     com.apple.ctkd
62097   -44     com.apple.AddressBook.ContactsAccountsService
-       0       com.apple.warmd_agent
-       0       com.apple.PubSub.Agent
-       0       com.apple.pictd
-       0       com.apple.universalaccesscontrol
62145   -44     com.apple.Safari.SafeBrowsing.Service
-       0       com.apple.findmymacmessenger
-       0       com.apple.FilesystemUI
-       0       com.apple.pluginkit.pkreporter
-       0       com.apple.systemprofiler
-       0       com.apple.lateragent
-       0       com.apple.UserNotificationCenterAgent
408     0       com.apple.noticeboard.agent
-       0       com.apple.dt.CommandLineTools.installondemand
-       -44     com.apple.cmfsyncagent
52395   -44     com.apple.cloudd
-       0       com.apple.ATS.FontValidator
411     0       com.apple.diagnostics_agent
-       0       com.apple.appleseed.seedusaged
-       0       com.apple.PhotoLibraryMigrationUtility.XPC
-       0       com.apple.LocalAuthentication.UIAgent
4862    0       com.openssh.ssh-agent
62123   -44     com.apple.networkserviceproxy
-       0       com.apple.tonelibraryd
64070   -44     com.apple.CloudPhotosConfiguration
-       -44     com.apple.spotlight.IndexAgent
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.bundles
-       -44     com.apple.mdworker.single.05000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       -44     com.apple.mdworker.lsb.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
62486   -44     com.apple.sbd
62098   -44     com.apple.secinitd
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_i386_1
-       0       com.apple.facebook.xpc
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_i386
-       0       com.apple.ctkbind
64061   -44     com.apple.cloudphotosd
-       0       com.apple.alf.useragent
62069   -44     com.apple.tccd
62505   -44     com.apple.coreservices.uiagent
-       0       com.apple.installd.user
-       0       com.apple.ContainerRepairAgent
62087   -44     com.apple.akd
-       -44     com.apple.CallHistoryPluginHelper
-       0       com.apple.NetworkDiagnostics
-       0       com.apple.InstallerProgress
431     0       com.apple.storeaccountd
-       0       com.apple.PCIESlotCheck
62198   -44     com.apple.security.keychainsyncingoveridsproxy
-       0       com.apple.PIPAgent
-       0       com.apple.mbfloagent
-       0       com.apple.AddressBook.AssistantService
-       0       com.apple.quicklook.32bit
-       -44     com.apple.printtool.agent
-       0       com.apple.IMLoggingAgent
1741    0       com.apple.USBAgent
52235   -44     com.apple.nsurlstoraged
401     0       com.apple.askpermissiond
-       0       com.apple.webinspectord
-       0       com.apple.ssinvitationagent
-       0       com.valvesoftware.steamclean
-       0       com.apple.WebKit.PluginAgent
-       0       com.apple.speech.synthesisserver
-       0       com.apple.DiagnosticReportCleanup.plist
59491   0       com.apple.storeuid
-       0       com.apple.speech.speechdatainstallerd
-       0       com.apple.rcd
-       0       com.apple.quicklook.config
62474   -44     com.apple.printuitool.agent
-       0       com.apple.AOSHeartbeat
62202   -44     com.apple.CryptoTokenKit.ahp.agent
-       0       com.apple.SafariNotificationAgent
-       0       com.apple.appsleep
-       0       com.dropbox.DropboxMacUpdate.agent.install.3911000115
-       0       org.macosforge.xquartz.startx
-       0       com.apple.FileStatsAgent
62085   -44     com.apple.coreservices.useractivityd
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.single.03000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_x86_64_1
-       0       com.apple.netauth.user.auth
61797   -44     com.apple.ViewBridgeAuxiliary
-       0       com.apple.mbbackgrounduseragent
335     0       com.apple.lsd
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64
-       0       com.apple.sharekit.EntitlementsHelper
-       0       com.apple.weibo.xpc
62508   -44     com.apple.pluginkit.pkd
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_x86_64
-       0       com.apple.security.XPCTimeStampingService
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.single.08000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.maspushagent
-       -44     com.apple.FolderActionsDispatcher
64057   -44     com.apple.cache_delete
-       0       com.apple.personad
-       -44     com.apple.CallHistorySyncHelper
-       0       com.apple.accessibility.dfrhud
62119   -44     com.apple.parsecd
332     0       com.apple.Dock.agent
327     0       com.apple.UserEventAgent-Aqua
-       0       com.apple.mbuseragent
-       0       com.apple.ReportPanic
62089   -44     com.apple.followupd
62094   -44     com.apple.telephonyutilities.callservicesd
350     0       com.apple.identityservicesd
-       0       com.apple.DwellControl
-       0       com.apple.imavagent
5930    0       com.apple.security.DiskUnmountWatcher
-       0       com.apple.CoreLocationAgent
-       0       com.apple.security.agent
480     0       com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000005.TabletDriver
-       0       com.apple.cfnetwork.AuthBrokerAgent
357     0       com.apple.storedownloadd
406     0       com.apple.cloudpaird
342     0       com.apple.pboard
368     0       com.apple.coreservices.sharedfilelistd
457     0       com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000004.ConsumerTouchDriver
-       0       com.apple.reversetemplated
-       0       com.apple.nowplayingtouchui
-       0       com.apple.thermaltrap
-       -44     com.apple.SafariCloudHistoryPushAgent
-       0       com.apple.AskPermissionUI
64026   0       com.apple.mdworker.shared.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.accounts.dom
62200   -44     com.apple.security.cloudkeychainproxy3
519     0       com.apple.metadata.mdflagwriter
-       -44     com.apple.DictionaryServiceHelper
898     0       com.apple.speech.speechsynthesisd
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.shared
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.single.06000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.isolation
-       0       com.apple.messages.BuddyPictureService
-       0       com.apple.installandsetup.migrationhelper.user
-       -44     com.apple.imdpersistence.IMDPersistenceAgent
-       0       com.apple.TrustEvaluationAgent
-       0       com.apple.tiswitcher
-       0       com.apple.eosauthagent
62491   -44     com.apple.cdpd
349     0       com.apple.accountsd
-       0       com.apple.storelegacy
62261   -44     com.apple.OSDUIHelper
-       0       com.apple.locationmenu
64073   -44     com.apple.AssetCacheLocatorService
62124   -44     com.apple.videosubscriptionsd
62480   -44     com.apple.protectedcloudstorage.protectedcloudkeysyncing
62338   -44     com.apple.pbs
391     0       com.apple.notificationcenterui.agent
392     0       com.apple.imklaunchagent
-       0       com.apple.imcore.imtransferagent
-       0       com.apple.FTCleanup
-       0       com.apple.btsa
-       0       com.apple.bluetooth.PacketLogger
394     0       com.apple.icdd
62481   -44     com.apple.EscrowSecurityAlert
62102   -44     com.apple.coreservices.appleid.authentication
1988    0       com.apple.metadata.mdwrite
-       0       com.apple.loginwindow.LWWeeklyMessageTracer
-       0       com.apple.screencapturetb.agent
399     0       com.apple.CalendarAgent
-       0       com.apple.RapportUIAgent
-       0       com.apple.powerchime
402     0       com.apple.sharingd
-       0       org.mozilla.firefox.4716
477     0       com.apple.storeassetd
-       0       com.apple.iCloudUserNotificationsd
-       0       com.apple.familycircled
-       0       com.oracle.java.Java-Updater
-       0       com.apple.ReportCrash.Self
371     0       com.apple.imagent
-       0       com.apple.FontRegistryUIAgent
-       0       com.apple.syncservices.SyncServer
62120   -44     com.apple.photoanalysisd
-       0       com.apple.ZoomWindow
-       0       com.apple.talagent
334     0       com.apple.SystemUIServer.agent
62118   -44     com.apple.suggestd
-       0       com.apple.storeinappd
-       0       com.apple.imautomatichistorydeletionagent
-       0       com.apple.ATS.FontValidatorConduit
3085    0       com.apple.Terminal.3332
-       0       com.apple.navd
-       0       com.apple.VoiceOver
-       0       com.apple.RemoteDesktop.agent
-       0       com.apple.cloudfamilyrestrictionsd
-       -44     com.apple.icloud.fmfd
-       0       com.apple.AssistiveControl
-       -44     com.apple.CoreSimulator.CoreSimulatorService
-       -44     com.apple.mdworker.32bit.01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.shared.00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.32bit
59590   -44     com.apple.secd
-       -44     com.apple.appstore.PluginXPCService
62337   -44     com.apple.hiservices-xpcservice
-       -44     com.apple.BKAgentService
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_x86_64_1
-       0       com.apple.tencentweibo.xpc
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_i386_1
-       0       com.apple.FCiCloudPrefUpdater
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_i386_1
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_i386
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.lsb
62163   -44     com.apple.assistantd
-       0       com.apple.FollowUpUI
-       0       com.apple.videoconference.camera
1605    0       com.apple.controlstrip
-       0       com.apple.mediaanalysisd
-       0       com.apple.isst
-       0       com.apple.DiskArbitrationAgent
64052   0       com.coteditor.CotEditor.2752
62148   -44     com.apple.scopedbookmarksagent.xpc
-       0       com.apple.ReportCrash
374     0       com.apple.fontd
62278   -44     com.apple.Maps.mapspushd
-       0       com.apple.STMUIHelper
62086   -44     com.apple.gamed
-       0       com.spotify.webhelper
-       0       com.apple.java.updateSharing
-       0       com.apple.eospreflightagent
-       0       com.apple.midiserver
-       0       com.apple.quicklook.ui.helper
64054   0       com.apple.helpd
410     0       com.apple.wifi.WiFiAgent
-       0       com.apple.screensharing.MessagesAgent
62502   -44     com.apple.diskspaced
412     0       com.apple.passd
-       0       com.apple.FirmwareUpdateHelper
-       0       com.nvidia.CUDASoftwareUpdate
-       0       com.apple.DictationIM
-       -44     com.apple.CoreAuthentication.agent
-       0       com.apple.mdmclient.agent
64049   0       com.apple.iCloudHelper
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.single.07000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       -44     com.apple.mdworker.single.01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.iBooksX.CacheDelete
-       0       com.apple.storeinstallagent
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3425AMD_x86_64
-       0       com.apple.linkedin.xpc
-       0       com.apple.security.XPCKeychainSandboxCheck
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.single
64038   0       com.apple.mdworker.shared.03000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.twitter.xpc
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgentLegacy_x86_64_1
-       0       org.mozilla.firefox.4196
-       0       com.apple.scrod
-       -44     com.apple.spindump_agent
62281   -44     com.apple.softwareupdate_notify_agent
-       0       com.apple.security.keychain-circle-notification
-       0       com.apple.icloud.findmydeviced.findmydevice-user-agent
-       0       com.github.GitHubClient.ShipIt
-       0       com.google.keystone.user.agent
-       0       com.apple.universalaccessd
62478   0       com.apple.AirPortBaseStationAgent
-       0       com.apple.appstoreupdateagent
-       0       com.apple.SafariLaunchAgent
-       -44     com.apple.recentsd
-       0       com.apple.neagent
-       0       com.apple.idsfoundation.IDSRemoteURLConnectionAgent
62422   -44     com.apple.WiFiVelocityAgent
397     0       com.apple.usernoted
-       0       com.apple.SafariPlugInUpdateNotifier
64060   -44     com.apple.geodMachServiceBridge
-       0       com.apple.AddressBook.abd
-       0       com.apple.ScreenReaderUIServer
-       -44     com.apple.swcd
405     0       com.apple.AirPlayUIAgent
-       0       com.dropbox.DropboxMacUpdate.agent
407     0       com.wacom.pentablet
-       0       com.apple.safaridavclient
-       0       com.apple.touchbar.agent
-       0       com.apple.netauth.user.gui
-       0       com.apple.TMHelperAgent
475     0       com.apple.Spotlight
62067   -44     com.apple.soagent
-       -44     com.apple.mdworker.32bit.02000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       -44     com.apple.accessibility.mediaaccessibilityd
62493   0       com.apple.syncdefaultsd
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3425AMD_x86_64_1
995     0       com.apple.mdworker.sizing
-       0       com.apple.SpeechRecognitionCore.brokerd
-       0       com.apple.metadata.mdbulkimport
64043   0       com.apple.mdworker.shared.01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
-       0       com.apple.iokit.IOServiceAuthorizeAgent
62386   -44     com.apple.Safari.History
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent3600_x86_64
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.single.04000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
329     0       com.apple.distnoted.xpc.agent
-       0       com.apple.cvmsCompAgent_i386
-       0       com.apple.mdworker.lsb.01000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
62122   -44     com.apple.geod
```

Answer (score 2):

The first column displays the PID of the job if it is running.  The second column displays the last exit status of the job.

If the number in this column is negative, it represents the negative of the signal which stopped the job. Thus, "-15" would indicate that the job was terminated with SIGTERM.

Those can be either Unix Signals and/or BSD Signals.

`man sigaction` tells about every Signal possibilities.

`man signal` list their codes.

---

I have looked inside the source code of **launchctl.c** and I found it can **also** return any of these codes:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 2000-2012 Apple, Inc. All rights reserved.
 *
 * @APPLE_OSREFERENCE_LICENSE_HEADER_START@
 *
 * This file contains Original Code and/or Modifications of Original Code
 * as defined in and that are subject to the Apple Public Source License
 * Version 2.0 (the 'License'). You may not use this file except in
 * compliance with the License. The rights granted to you under the License
 * may not be used to create, or enable the creation or redistribution of,
 * unlawful or unlicensed copies of an Apple operating system, or to
 * circumvent, violate, or enable the circumvention or violation of, any
 * terms of an Apple operating system software license agreement.
 *
 * Please obtain a copy of the License at
 * http://www.opensource.apple.com/apsl/ and read it before using this file.
 *
 * The Original Code and all software distributed under the License are
 * distributed on an 'AS IS' basis, WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EITHER
 * EXPRESS OR IMPLIED, AND APPLE HEREBY DISCLAIMS ALL SUCH WARRANTIES,
 * INCLUDING WITHOUT LIMITATION, ANY WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE, QUIET ENJOYMENT OR NON-INFRINGEMENT.
 * Please see the License for the specific language governing rights and
 * limitations under the License.
 *
 * @APPLE_OSREFERENCE_LICENSE_HEADER_END@
 */
/* Copyright (c) 1995 NeXT Computer, Inc. All Rights Reserved */
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1982, 1986, 1989, 1993
 *      The Regents of the University of California.  All rights reserved.
 * (c) UNIX System Laboratories, Inc.


#ifndef _SYS_ERRNO_H_
#define _SYS_ERRNO_H_

#include <sys/cdefs.h>

#if !defined(KERNEL) && !defined(KERNEL_PRIVATE)

#if defined(__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__) && __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ >= 1
#include <sys/_types/_errno_t.h>
#endif


/*
 * Error codes
 */

#define EPERM           1               /* Operation not permitted */
#define ENOENT          2               /* No such file or directory */
#define ESRCH           3               /* No such process */
#define EINTR           4               /* Interrupted system call */
#define EIO             5               /* Input/output error */
#define ENXIO           6               /* Device not configured */
#define E2BIG           7               /* Argument list too long */
#define ENOEXEC         8               /* Exec format error */
#define EBADF           9               /* Bad file descriptor */
#define ECHILD          10              /* No child processes */
#define EDEADLK         11              /* Resource deadlock avoided */
                                        /* 11 was EAGAIN */
#define ENOMEM          12              /* Cannot allocate memory */
#define EACCES          13              /* Permission denied */
#define EFAULT          14              /* Bad address */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define ENOTBLK         15              /* Block device required */
#endif
#define EBUSY           16              /* Device / Resource busy */
#define EEXIST          17              /* File exists */
#define EXDEV           18              /* Cross-device link */
#define ENODEV          19              /* Operation not supported by device */
#define ENOTDIR         20              /* Not a directory */
#define EISDIR          21              /* Is a directory */
#define EINVAL          22              /* Invalid argument */
#define ENFILE          23              /* Too many open files in system */
#define EMFILE          24              /* Too many open files */
#define ENOTTY          25              /* Inappropriate ioctl for device */
#define ETXTBSY         26              /* Text file busy */
#define EFBIG           27              /* File too large */
#define ENOSPC          28              /* No space left on device */
#define ESPIPE          29              /* Illegal seek */
#define EROFS           30              /* Read-only file system */
#define EMLINK          31              /* Too many links */
#define EPIPE           32              /* Broken pipe */

/* math software */
#define EDOM            33              /* Numerical argument out of domain */
#define ERANGE          34              /* Result too large */

/* non-blocking and interrupt i/o */
#define EAGAIN          35              /* Resource temporarily unavailable */
#define EWOULDBLOCK     EAGAIN          /* Operation would block */
#define EINPROGRESS     36              /* Operation now in progress */
#define EALREADY        37              /* Operation already in progress */

/* ipc/network software -- argument errors */
#define ENOTSOCK        38              /* Socket operation on non-socket */
#define EDESTADDRREQ    39              /* Destination address required */
#define EMSGSIZE        40              /* Message too long */
#define EPROTOTYPE      41              /* Protocol wrong type for socket */
#define ENOPROTOOPT     42              /* Protocol not available */
#define EPROTONOSUPPORT 43              /* Protocol not supported */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define ESOCKTNOSUPPORT 44              /* Socket type not supported */
#endif
#define ENOTSUP         45              /* Operation not supported */
#if !__DARWIN_UNIX03 && !defined(KERNEL)
#if !__DARWIN_UNIX03 && !defined(KERNEL)
/*
 * This is the same for binary and source copmpatability, unless compiling
 * the kernel itself, or compiling __DARWIN_UNIX03; if compiling for the
 * kernel, the correct value will be returned.  If compiling non-POSIX
 * source, the kernel return value will be converted by a stub in libc, and
 * if compiling source with __DARWIN_UNIX03, the conversion in libc is not
 * done, and the caller gets the expected (discrete) value.
 */
#define EOPNOTSUPP       ENOTSUP        /* Operation not supported on socket */
#endif /* !__DARWIN_UNIX03 && !KERNEL */

#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define EPFNOSUPPORT    46              /* Protocol family not supported */
#endif
#define EAFNOSUPPORT    47              /* Address family not supported by protocol family */
#define EADDRINUSE      48              /* Address already in use */
#define EADDRNOTAVAIL   49              /* Can't assign requested address */

/* ipc/network software -- operational errors */
#define ENETDOWN        50              /* Network is down */
#define ENETUNREACH     51              /* Network is unreachable */
#define ENETRESET       52              /* Network dropped connection on reset */
#define ECONNABORTED    53              /* Software caused connection abort */
#define ECONNRESET      54              /* Connection reset by peer */
#define ENOBUFS         55              /* No buffer space available */
#define EISCONN         56              /* Socket is already connected */
#define ENOTCONN        57              /* Socket is not connected */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define ESHUTDOWN       58              /* Can't send after socket shutdown */
#define ETOOMANYREFS    59              /* Too many references: can't splice */
#endif
#define ETIMEDOUT       60              /* Operation timed out */
#define ECONNREFUSED    61              /* Connection refused */

#define ELOOP           62              /* Too many levels of symbolic links */
#define ENAMETOOLONG    63              /* File name too long */

/* should be rearranged */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define EHOSTDOWN       64              /* Host is down */
#endif
#define EHOSTUNREACH    65              /* No route to host */
#define ENOTEMPTY       66              /* Directory not empty */

/* quotas & mush */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define EPROCLIM        67              /* Too many processes */
#define EUSERS          68              /* Too many users */
#endif
#define EDQUOT          69              /* Disc quota exceeded */

/* Network File System */
#define ESTALE          70              /* Stale NFS file handle */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define EREMOTE         71              /* Too many levels of remote in path */
#define EBADRPC         72              /* RPC struct is bad */
#define ERPCMISMATCH    73              /* RPC version wrong */
#define EPROGUNAVAIL    74              /* RPC prog. not avail */
#define EPROGMISMATCH   75              /* Program version wrong */
#define EPROCUNAVAIL    76              /* Bad procedure for program */
#endif

#define ENOLCK          77              /* No locks available */
#define ENOSYS          78              /* Function not implemented */


#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define EFTYPE          79              /* Inappropriate file type or format */
#define EAUTH           80              /* Authentication error */
#define ENEEDAUTH       81              /* Need authenticator */

/* Intelligent device errors */
#define EPWROFF         82      /* Device power is off */
#define EDEVERR         83      /* Device error, e.g. paper out */
#endif

#define EOVERFLOW       84              /* Value too large to be stored in data type */

/* Program loading errors */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define EBADEXEC        85      /* Bad executable */
#define EBADARCH        86      /* Bad CPU type in executable */
#define ESHLIBVERS      87      /* Shared library version mismatch */
#define EBADMACHO       88      /* Malformed Macho file */
#endif

#define ECANCELED       89              /* Operation canceled */

#define EIDRM           90              /* Identifier removed */
#define ENOMSG          91              /* No message of desired type */
#define EILSEQ          92              /* Illegal byte sequence */
#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define ENOATTR         93              /* Attribute not found */
#endif

#define EBADMSG         94              /* Bad message */
#define EMULTIHOP       95              /* Reserved */
#define ENODATA         96              /* No message available on STREAM */
#define ENOLINK         97              /* Reserved */
#define ENOSR           98              /* No STREAM resources */
#define ENOSTR          99              /* Not a STREAM */
#define EPROTO          100             /* Protocol error */
#define ETIME           101             /* STREAM ioctl timeout */

#if __DARWIN_UNIX03 || defined(KERNEL)
/* This value is only discrete when compiling __DARWIN_UNIX03, or KERNEL */
#define EOPNOTSUPP      102             /* Operation not supported on socket */
#endif /* __DARWIN_UNIX03 || KERNEL */

#define ENOPOLICY       103             /* No such policy registered */

#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= 200809L
#define ENOTRECOVERABLE 104             /* State not recoverable */
#define EOWNERDEAD      105             /* Previous owner died */
#endif

#if __DARWIN_C_LEVEL >= __DARWIN_C_FULL
#define EQFULL          106             /* Interface output queue is full */
#define ELAST           106             /* Must be equal largest errno */
#endif

#ifdef KERNEL
/* pseudo-errors returned inside kernel to modify return to process */
#define ERESTART        (-1)            /* restart syscall */
#define EJUSTRETURN     (-2)            /* don't modify regs, just return */

#ifdef KERNEL_PRIVATE
#define ERECYCLE    (-5)                /* restart lookup under heavy vnode pressure/recycling */
#endif
#endif
#ifdef BSD_KERNEL_PRIVATE
#define EREDRIVEOPEN    (-6)
#define EKEEPLOOKING    (-7)
/* used for cvwait error returns to Libc */
#define ECVCERORR       256
#define ECVPERORR       512
#else /* BSD_KERNEL_PRIVATE */
/* -5, -6 and -7 and -106 are reserved for kernel internal use */
#endif /* BSD_KERNEL_PRIVATE */
#ifdef PRIVATE
#define EQSUSPENDED     (-EQFULL)       /* Output queue is suspended */
#endif /* PRIVATE */
#endif /* KERNEL */
#endif /* _SYS_ERRNO_H_ */
```

---

Code -44 is "Socket not supported" and looking at the processes you listed, all that have -44 are related to internet and/or iCloud stuff. Things that may return -44 while either on sleep mode or while you are disconnected from internet, or some similar situation.

Comment: Thanks, the enlightening part of your explanation is the possible meaning of exit status -44, SIGNOTIFY. I already knew the rest, though SIGNOTIFY was exactly what I was looking for. Hoping that it is correct (since I am not able to find a lookup table anywhere on the Web, that includes -44) I have an idea of what is happening there, now. Possibly computer sleep notifications (I do never shot down it). I just tried to shot down it few minutes ago and it does not display those signals yet.

Comment: I updated my answer with a table reference. It makes sense! Code -44 is "Socket not supported" and looking at your processes all that have -44 are related to internet and/or iCloud stuff. Things that may return -44 while either on sleep mode or while you are disconnected from internet.

Comment: It's about a week now, that I am monitoring (now and then) the exit status values, after a reboot of the system, and I never seen the -44 exit status code anymore. I start to think that our guess was wrong. I am still watching for the network related explanation since all those services are somehow related to network.